# How to change the string when the string is present

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code. I have a trouble with changing the strings.

I am checking with the strings if the variable `getTime3` have a string `30` then I want to replace it with `00`. On my code, it will find the string `30` to replace it with `0030` which is wrong. It should be `00`.

Here is the code:

```
if getTime3 == '11:30PM':
   self.getControl(346).setLabel('12:00AM')
elif getTime3 == '12:30PM':
     self.getControl(346).setLabel('1:00AM')
else:
    ind = getTime3.find(':')
    if getTime3[ind+1:ind+3]=='30':
       getTime3 = getTime3[:ind]+':00'+getTime3[+2:]
       self.getControl(346).setLabel(getTime3)

    else: 
       getTime3 = str(int(getTime3[:ind])+1)+':30'+getTime3[+2:]
       self.getControl(346).setLabel(getTime3)
```

What I am expect for the two special cases, when the program finds the `:`, it will check if `30` is present then change the current hour to the next hour and make a new string with AM/PM label, example: change from `8` to `9` and replace `30` with `00` to make it to show `9:00PM`. If the ending is `00` then I want to change `00` to `30` instead. I want to add `30` in the minute section and again preserves the AM/PM part. If the `getTime3` have the string `11:30AM` then I want to change it to `12:00PM`.

Can you please help me with how to fix the `0030` to make it to show `00` instead and add the next hour?

Comment: `getTime3[+2:]` - don't you want `getTime3[ind+2:]`?

Comment: That is used for `PM` which I need it.

Comment: Right, but what exactly is `+2`?

Comment: it show this `00PM`

Answer (score 1):

With Python, slice like `x[a:b]` in the slice starting at `a` (inclusive), and finishing at `b` (exclusive).

So: `getTime3[:ind]` is the slice from 0 to *ind* exclusive, which is the hours **without** the ":".

And indexes are absolute index, not relative. So `getTime3[+2:]` is the same as `getTime3[2:]`, which correspond to the substring starting at index 2.

What you want is:

```
getTime3 = getTime3[:ind] + ':00' + getTime3[ind + 3:]
# or
getTime3 = getTime3[:ind + 1] + '00' + getTime3[ind + 3:]
```

Example:

```
getTime3 = '08:30PM'
ind = getTime3.index(":")
getTime3[:ind] + ':00' + getTime3[ind + 3:]
# -> '08:00PM'
```

**EDIT**

If you want to do some calculation on time, you can use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module.

```
time_fmt = '%I:%M%p'
```

Is the format used to represent time like '09:30PM', where:

- %I Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
- %M Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
- %p Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM.

How to add 30 min:

```
import datetime

time3 = '09:30PM'
dt3 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time3, time_fmt)
dt3 += datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
time3 = dt3.strftime(time_fmt)
```

If you want to set the minutes to 0, you can do:

```
dt3 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time3, time_fmt)
dt3 = d3.replace(minute=0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, when I try this: `ind = getTime3.find(':')
                                             if getTime3[ind+1:ind+3] == '30':
                                                 getTime3 = str(int(getTime3[:ind]) + 1)+':00'+ getTime3[ind+2:]` it will show `10:000PM`. How I can make it to show `10:00PM` when my string show the time `9:30PM`?

Comment: @DanielEzekiel: If you need to do calculation on date/time, you should consider using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module.

Comment: if I use datetime module, are they going to add the minute and day date automatically as if my time show `11:30PM` then it will add it to `12:00AM` to the next day, the same for the month and year?

Comment: @DanielEzekiel Yes, a `datetime` object is the combination of a date and a time. So 11:30PM + 30min = 23:30 + 30 min = 0:00 (midnight the day after). To have relevant time you need to add a "real" date to your `datetime` object. Read the documentation…

Answer (score -1):

Please don't use the wrong tool for the task. You are manipulating times, yet using strings to do it. Start with this to turn 11:30PM into 12:00AM:

```
import datetime
t3 = datetime.datetime.strptime(getTime3, '%I:%M%p')
t3 += datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
print(t3.strftime('%I:%M%p'))
```

Adding `timedelta(minutes=30)` makes the intent perfectly clear. Some relevant documentation is at https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: I have the datetime_strptime which show `time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=10, tm_hour=20, tm_min=30, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=253, tm_isdst=-1` when I am using `epg_time_1 = self.epg_time_1` to store time.struct_time in the list. How I can add 30 mins using with time.struct_time?

Comment: You are showing `t3.timetuple()` results compatible with time.localtime(). Don't do that, just stick to the datetime module, adding a timedelta as I described.